# Concurrent wireless and wired network

Tags: windows-networking

I am concerned with maintaining a wireless and wired network connection on my laptop. Basically I can change the metric on each interface so that Windows prefers one connection over the other. I am wondering is following scenario possible....

Some applications uses the wireless while other applications use the wired... I want Internet Explorer (only) to use the wireless connection while Outlook and everything else uses the wired connection. Perhaps adding some lines to the routing table might work? - Adding the ip addresses of websites I want to view via the wireless connection?

Many Thanks in advance for any replies!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this with [**ForceBindIP**](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/). Bind iexplore.exe to your wireless interface and give it a go :)

About ForceBindIP:

> ForceBindIP is a freeware Windows
>   application that will inject itself
>   into another application and alter how
>   certain Windows Sockets calls are
>   made, allowing you to force the other
>   application to use a specific network
>   interface / IP address. This is useful
>   if you are in an environment with
>   multiple interfaces and your
>   application has no such option for
>   binding to a specific interface.